# Json Listview wont refresh after spinner event

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview

My issue is i have a list of products on my listview, when i select one of the values from my spinner i save it and send it to retrieve different values from my mysql database, The problem i have is that my listview wont update after i perform the onclick event on my spinner, what am I doing wrong? I dont know if i managed to explain correctly what i want to say, thank you for your help

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int pos, long id)
                {
                    filtracat();
                }


private void filtracat() {
    cat = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
     valor = String.valueOf(cat);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),valor,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_CAT, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            hideDialog();
            //parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Anuncios item = new Anuncios();
                    item.setKey(obj.getString("key"));
                    item.setTitulo(obj.getString("titulo"));
                    item.setImageID(obj.getString("imageID"));
                    item.setModelo(obj.getString("modelo"));
                    item.setPreco(obj.getString("preco"));
                    //gonna set category here
                    //    item.setCategoria(obj.getString("categoria"));
                    //add to array
                    array2.add(item);
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("valor", valor);
            return params;
        }


    };
AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

the original data from my listview comes from

```
 private void sendRequest() {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            hideDialog();
            //parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Anuncios item = new Anuncios();
                    item.setKey(obj.getString("key"));
                    item.setTitulo(obj.getString("titulo"));
                    item.setImageID(obj.getString("imageID"));
                    item.setModelo(obj.getString("modelo"));
                    item.setPreco(obj.getString("preco"));
                    //gonna set category here
                //    item.setCategoria(obj.getString("categoria"));
                    //add to array
                    array.add(item);
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

should i be using the same array to update the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Create Two object

   ```
         ArrayList<MobileKeyModel> dropDownModels = new ArrayList<MobileKeyModel>();
         ArrayList<Object> addList = new ArrayList<Object>();
   ```
2. You can get response from database

   ```
      private void filtracat() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {

                   try {
                       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                       JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("parentnodesList");
                       for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                           String key = jo.getString("key");
                           String titulo = jo.getString("titulo");
                           addList.add(key);
                           addList.add(titulo);
                       }

                       pupulateDropDownList();
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   try {
                       //Respose Error

                   } catch (Exception e) {


                   }
               }
           }) {
       @Override
       protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
           Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
           return params;
       }

   };


     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
   ```
3. populate value to listview

   void pupulateDropDownList() {

   ```
   if (addList != null) {
       for (Iterator<Object> i = addList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
           MobileKeyModel menuModel = new MobileKeyModel(i.next().toString(), i.next().toString());
           dropDownModels.add(menuModel);

       }

       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_text, dropDownModels);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      }
   }
   ```
4. Model is also here

   public class MobileKeyModel {

   ```
   public String key = "";
   public String titulo = "";

   public MobileKeyModel(String key, String titulo) {
       this.key = key;
       this.titulo = titulo;
   }

   public String getKey() {
       return key;
   }

   public void setKey(String key) {
       this.key = key;
   }

   public String getTitulo() {
       return titulo;
   }

   public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
       this.titulo = titulo;
   }
   ```

   }
5. Note Your json must be look like

   ```
       {"parentnodesList":[{"key":"your key value here","titulo":"Your title"}]}
   ```

Comment: thanks for the feedback Enamul, i dont want to add what i select from my spinner to my listview, what i was trying to do was to filter the original listview, and send the value from my spinner so that i could filter the listview to only the products of 1 of the categories, but my listview will not update... i already have the spinner populated, i just need the id, and then on my php i will select only the products with that category id